# vb.net programmatically added binding not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I am trying to bind a variable value to a button's content property. i created a button named "button" inside a dockpanel of my main window in XAML.

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Height="100" 
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
```

Then I want to add a binding to a public variable `test` programmatically.
The initial value (400) is displayed correctly at runtime, but when I hit the "NextTurn" button to raise the Click event, the bound value isn't updated.

```
Imports System.Windows.Data

    Class MainWindow

        Public test As Integer

        Public Sub New()

            InitializeComponent()

            Dim usr As New UserNS.User
            mainUser = usr
            test = 400
            Dim btest As New Binding()
            btest.Source = test
            button.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, btest)

        End Sub

 Private Sub NextTurn_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles NextTurn.Click

            test = test - 10

        End Sub
End Class
```

Could you please help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `Class` that contains properties for binding should realize `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface (you can find typical implementation in msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). And property setter should call Notify function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all, fields cannot be bound, only properties.
2. The binding source should be an object which has the property you would like to bind.
   Ideally it is not the form class itself but a separate class (aka. view model).
   E.g. the main window (named `MainWindow`) can have a view model named `MainViewModel`.
3. This object must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
4. In the property setter you have to call a method which raises the `PropertyChanged` event that comes with `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

   In my example it is:
   `Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(...)`

**IMPORTANT:** VB.NET works in case-insensitive mode so avoid naming a `Button` control as `button`. Also if you implement a full property the backing field should have a different name. You cannot have a `test` field and a `Test` property at the same time. That's why I chose the `_Test` name for the field.

Here is a working example:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Class MainWindow
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Sub New()

        ' Actually we can initialize the Test property here as well.

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Test = 400

        Dim bindingTest As New Binding() With {
            .Source = Me, ' The object which has the property we want to bind.
            .Mode = BindingMode.OneWay, ' We declare that the UI will accept changes from the object's property but not vica-versa.
            .Path = New PropertyPath("Test") 'We have to pass the name of the property as a String value.
        }

        TestButton.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty, bindingTest)

        ' We could also initialize the Test property here.

    End Sub

    ' We can also initialize only the field instead of the property
    ' But new values must be set through the property setter.
    Private _Test As Integer
    Public Property Test() As Integer
        Get
            Return _Test
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _Test = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged()
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    ' We use CallerMemberName attribute so that we do not need to pass the name of the property.
    ' The compiler will automatically pass the name of the caller property. In our case: "Test"
    ' To get it work we declare the parameter as Optional so that we really do not have to pass a parameter value.
    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(<CallerMemberName()> Optional ByVal propertyName As String = "")
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Private Sub NextTurnButton_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        ' You must set the property's value instead of the backing field!
        Test = Test - 10
    End Sub

End Class
```